# complex numbers/trig

Tags: vectors

express $(-1 +j)$ in the form $re^{j\theta}$ where $r$ is positive and $-\pi<\theta<\pi$

The answer is $ \sqrt{2} e^{j \cdot 2.3562}$

My query is, that on the way to getting the answer I have $\cos\theta = -1/\sqrt{2}$ and $\sin\theta = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

thus $\cos^{-1} = 2.3562$  but when I do $\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{2})$ I do not get $2.3562$.  I suspect that this has something to do with radians and trig, two of my weak points.  I have set my calculator to radians.

Comment: what do mean :$ -pie $

Comment: @Cardinal, he means $-\pi$.

Comment: Why all the down votes ? Anyone care to explain? I think this is a valid question and the OP is showing his progress and where is he having troubles...

Comment: Calculators must use functions in order to display a single answer. You are running into the issue that the inverse cosine function has its range over $ \ 0 \ \le \ \theta \ \le \ \pi \ $ , but the inverse sine function has the range $ \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ \le \ \theta \ \le \ +\frac{\pi}{2} \ $ .  When working with a calculator, one must ask the questions, "What quadrant must the angle be in?" and "What angle _in that quadrant_ has those sine and cosine values?".  A positive sine and _negative_ cosine means your angle is in the _second_ quadrant, so the angle must be $ \ \frac{3 \pi}{4} \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

HINT: with $a=-1,b=1$ you will get $r=\sqrt{1^1+1^1}$ and $\tan(\phi)=\frac{1}{-1}$